# Dot led P10 display line scroll function for scrolling string

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am working on developing a driver in c for P10 dot led panel. The driver is working great with max 2 displays, but the problem occurred when I tried to connect 3 displays in a road.

I made the P10 display as a 2 dimensional array (shown on the first picture).
This is the array for only 1 display. The array site is greenDisplayRAM [16][4] .I have 2 color and 2 different array.
The scroll function I am using is:

```
    int lineScroll(unsigned int line, int zeroBit, LedColor LEDColor) {
    switch (LEDColor) {
        case Green:
        {
            unsigned long long tam = 0;
            unsigned int y1 = line % 4;
            unsigned int y2 = line / 4;
            int owerFlow;
            zeroBit = 1 - zeroBit;

            owerFlow = (greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4)][y1] / 128)&0x01;
            tam = greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4)][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 1][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 2][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 3][y1];

            tam = tam << 1;
            tam = tam + zeroBit;

            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) ][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 24)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 1][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 16)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 2][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 8)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 3][y1] = (long long) (tam & 0xFF);

            return owerFlow;
        }
        case Red:
        {
            unsigned long long tam = 0;
            unsigned int y1 = line % 4;
            unsigned int y2 = line / 4;
            int owerFlow;
            zeroBit = 1 - zeroBit;

            owerFlow = (redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4)][y1] / 128)&0x01;
            tam = redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4)][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 1][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 2][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 3][y1];

            tam = tam << 1;
            tam = tam + zeroBit;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) ][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 24)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 1][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 16)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 2][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 8)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 4) + 3][y1] = (long long) (tam & 0xFF);
            return owerFlow;
        }
        default:
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
   }
```

This was working great. Then I connected 2 displays and modified the function above. The new function line scroll is:

```
int lineScroll(unsigned int line, int zeroBit, LedColor LEDColor) {
    switch (LEDColor) {
        case Green:
        {
            unsigned long long tam = 0;
            unsigned int y1 = line % 4;
            unsigned int y2 = line / 4;
            int owerFlow;
            zeroBit = 1 - zeroBit;

            owerFlow = (greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8)][y1] / 128)&0x01;
            tam = greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8)][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 1][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 2][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 3][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 4][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 5][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 6][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 7][y1];
            tam = tam << 1;
            tam = tam + zeroBit;

            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8)][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 56)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 1][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 48)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 2][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 40)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 3][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 32)&0xFF;


            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 4][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 24)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 5][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 16)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 6][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 8)&0xFF;
            greenDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 7][y1] = (long long) (tam & 0xFF);

            return owerFlow;
        }
        case Red:
        {
            unsigned long long tam = 0;
            unsigned int y1 = line % 4;
            unsigned int y2 = line / 4;
            int owerFlow;
            zeroBit = 1 - zeroBit;

            owerFlow = (redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8)][y1] / 128)&0x01;
            tam = redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8)][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 1][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 2][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 3][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 4][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 5][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 6][y1];
            tam = tam << 8;
            tam = tam + redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 7][y1];
            tam = tam << 1;
            tam = tam + zeroBit;

            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8)][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 56)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 1][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 48)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 2][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 40)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 3][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 32)&0xFF;


            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 4][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 24)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 5][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 16)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 6][y1] = (long long) (tam >> 8)&0xFF;
            redDisplayRAM[(y2 * 8) + 7][y1] = (long long) (tam & 0xFF);

            return owerFlow;
        }
        default:
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
   }
```

Then I tried to connect 3th display, but the logic that I used before for the line scroll function is not working here. 
The array for 3 displays is shown in the picture.

The idea was: the linescroll function to get the byte [11][0] and to shift it left for one bit, and to add the next bit that it needs to be shown on the zero bit. Shifting the byte to the left means that the bit will be added in the end of [10][0] and etc for the line
The way I am calling the function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 96; i++) { // for all columns 32 per display 3 display 96 columns
    for (w = 0; w < 16; w++) { //for all line in the display
       lineScroll(w,0, Green);
    }
__delay_ms(30);
}
```

So the function is called 16 times for 16 different lines that the displays has, and plus that much times we need to shift the bite ( in the example 3*32 (P10 has 32 colums))
Can you please give me some ideas of how to make this work for n number of displays?

I would appreciate any idea.

Comment: Which language, C or C++ (they are different languages)?  For example, C++ has `std::vector` which can be accessed like arrays and they are easier to pass to functions.

Comment: You `case`s in the `switch` statement look identical except for the array.  I recommend creating function with the content and pass an array.  You can call it with the red array in one `case` and the green array in the other `case`.

Comment: In your `lineScroll` function, you don't calculate the `owerflow` value.  You return an undefined value for both red and green.

Comment: The language is C.

Comment: The language is C.
The whole display is like a array shown above.Every byte is 8 bit and every bit is 1 led on the display.The function will take a last byte of the line selected and shift 1 bit to the left and the carry bit will be added to the next byte.. etc.
In the function I write i take all bytes from selected line and shift to the left and add the new zero bit but with this idea I have limit to the 8 byte or 64 columns.Now my idea is to shift byte by byte and take the carry and add to the next byte.

Comment: If the language is C, you should remove the C++ tag.